# how to Add the total amount price of the items inside a Cart using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="namesController">

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>        
          <th> Items </th>
          <th> Description </th>
          <th> Price </th>
          <th> action </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
          <td>{{item.name}}</td>
          <td>{{item.description}}</td> 
          <td>{{item.price}}</td>
          <td><button ng-click="addToCart(item)"> add to cart</button></td> 
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="myCart">
       <div class="table">
         <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
          <thead> 
             <tr>
               <th> Name </th>
               <th> price </th>
             </tr>
          <thead>

          <tbody>
             <tr ng-repeat="item in myCart">
               <td>{{item.name}}</td>
               <td>{{item.price}}</td>
             </tr>
       </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="myAmount">

 Amount <input style="margin-left:350px;" type="text" name="myAmount"     ng-value="amount" />  

</div>



</div>

<script>

var app= angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('namesController', function($scope) {

   //iniating the myCart object
   $scope.myCart = [];

   //items available in the table 
   $scope.items = [
  {"name":"Milk", "description":"Milk for 5-12 years old", "price":"$23"},
       {"name":"Beer", "description":"alcoholic beer", "price":"$5"},
       {"name":"foods", "description":"foods", "price":"$8"} 
              ];

  $scope.addItems = function(item) {
    $scope.items.push(item);
    $scope.item = {};
   };

  $scope.addToCart = function(item) {
        $scope.myCart.push(item);     
   };



  $scope.getTotalAmount = function() {
       var i = 0;
       for (i=0; i<$scope.myCart.length; i++) {
        $scope.myCart.item.price[i] * $scope.myCart.item.price[i];
        }
   };

  $scope.amount = "0.00";





});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

hello I just want to ask how to add the total amount I buy(items in myCart) in my Cart using angularjs. i tried all base in my knowledge but it seems nothing happens. hoping for someone to walk me through on this one. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.getTotalAmount = function() {
    var i = 0,
        sum = 0;

    for (; i < $scope.myCart.length; i++) {
        sum += (+$scope.myCart[i].price);
    }

    $scope.amount = sum;
};
```

This getTotalAmount function should work, provided you have numbers as price in your items like,

```
$scope.items = [
    { "name": "Milk", "description": "Milk for 5-12 years old", "price": 23 },
    { "name": "Beer", "description": "alcoholic beer", "price": 5 },
    { "name": "foods", "description": "foods", "price": 8 }
];
```

Comment: sir even if i change it to numbers. the output is this. i click "5" then next i click "23" the amount is 523 the combine the two numbers

Comment: u forgot to return the sum :) hehe but ur answer is good its work very well thanks sir

Answer (score 1):

I did a plunker to illustrate this : https://plnkr.co/edit/tXtowcva1KeAmGeL6gut?p=preview

You can accumalate price when you add an item :

```
  $scope.addToCart = function(item) {
    $scope.myCart.push(item);     
    $scope.amount += item.price;
  };
```

Comment: I like this approach with the caveat that each time a user adds or removes an item, math has to be done.  By summing the total only at the end, we can focus on only adding and removing items without worrying about anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Like one of the options:

```
$scope.getTotalAmount = function() {
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.myCart.length; i++){
        var product = $scope.myCart[i];
        total += product.price;
    }

    return total;
};
```

then just do what you need with

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in your `getTotalAmount()` function seems a bit off.  Try this:

```
 $scope.getTotalAmount = function() {
     var i = 0;
     var total = 0.0;

     for (i=0; i < $scope.myCart.length; i++) {
         total += $scope.myCart[i].price;
     }

     return total;
};
```